# How to access private/package protected fields and methods in Java module system?

Tags: javafx, reflection, module

I'm trying to access the horizontal `ScrollBar` for the `VirtualFlow` that is internal control for a `TableView`. My working environment:

- OS - Windows 10
- IDE - Eclipse v. 2020-03 (4.15.0)
- JDK - jdk-10.0.2
- Compiler - maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1 (m2E for Eclipse)

The code below attempts to access the `VirtualFlow` (which is a field named `flow` in `TableViewSkinBase`, the parent for the skin for the `TableView)`, and then to access the horizontal `ScrollBar`:

```
private void xxx() {
      final TableView<R> tableView = new TableView<>();
      final TableViewSkin<R> skin = (TableViewSkin<R>) tableView.getSkin();
      try {
           final Field flowField = TableViewSkinBase.class.getDeclaredField("flow");
           flowField.setAccessible(true);
           final Method hbarMethod = VirtualFlow.class.getDeclaredMethod("getHbar");
           hbarMethod.setAccessible(true);

           final VirtualFlow<IndexedCell<R>> flow = (VirtualFlow<IndexedCell<R>>) flowField.get(skin);
           ScrollBar hbar = (ScrollBar) flowField.get(flow);
      }
      catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

The snippet below is from the entry in the `.pom` file for the compiler plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-opens=javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=javafx.scene.control.skin=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

An `InaccessibleObjectException` is thrown at the `flowField.setAccessible(true)` line in the `try/catch` block with the message:

```
Unable to make field javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkinBase.flow accessible: module javafx.controls does not "opens javafx.scene.control.skin" to unnamed module @418e9723
```

I'm pretty sure there's more than one error here and would be grateful to have them pointed out; an example based on the working environment described above would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if this is a runtime exception: add the same add-opens to the runtime configuration

Comment: @kleopatra, thanks for your reply. As surmised in my question there was more than one error - the 'javafx.controls/' text needs to precede the 'javafx.scene.***' segment. The changes were added to the VM Arguments area in the Runtime configurations/Arguments tab (Eclipse IDE) and it works (except the skin is null but I can work around that). Question: is it possible to put the add-opens entries in the .pom to handle the runtime rather than rely on the Eclipse feature? That would centralize things and make maintenance easier?

Comment: not familiar with maven, sry

Comment: When the JavaFX developers did not provide public accessors, they do not want you to access these objects. So you are writing software which fights the intention of the library it uses and now, even is fighting the programming language (module system) it uses. Ask yourself what that means for the maintenance of the software…

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your comment. Your point is well-taken and understood. That notwithstanding I believe I have a fair understanding as to why the elements in question are restricted and do not consider those reasons well-founded; they've resulted in a platform having a design that is not as good as it could - and should - be. That seems to be especially true in the case of JavaFX, which from all appearances is experiencing growing pains in adapting to the detachment from its Oracle parent.

Comment: I have no doubt that your considerations regarding the API design are reasonable. We did evaluate JavaFX for our software projects and came to a similar conclusion, the (public) API is … ahem … insufficient for real life applications of a certain complexity. But writing an application constantly working-around an API or in other words, settling it on a library whose maintainers have a…different understanding how software should work, looked too risky. That was before the module introduction and before the removal of JavaFX from the JDK, so in hindsight, all worries were correct.

Comment: @Holger Thanks again, your insights are useful. To close the circle here, I'm using reflection here to finish a library project with the expectation that the 'official' API that is correctly restricted will eventually become public. My 'real' profession isn't software and I'm definitely not in your league as far as that goes. I belong instead to that not-so-revered group known as 'attorney' and program for legal and financial services. Once I finish the current project (JavaFX library) I hope to finish an application that can be used to combat money laundering.